# Error When Changing the Appearance of an Excel Table

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in tables in different sheets of a workbook. I want to use VBA to change the style of the table, hide a few columns. But ran into an error.

```vb
Sub j()

    Range("Table3[[#Headers],[Case Number]]").Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3").TableStyle = "TableStyleDark3"
    Columns("C:R").Select

    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Columns("S:S").Select

    Selection.ColumnWidth = 26
    Columns("B:B").Select
 
End Sub
```

Comment: What are the error number and the error description? Please describe what you are trying to do and what the code is doing so far. You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71092149/edit) at any time.

Comment: Hi,I have data in table format in different sheets.I  want to change table style,hide some colums and add data validation in one column.Now when i use macros it executes in one but when i try on different sheet,it says"subscript range not found","range 10004 error".Could you please kindly help me

Comment: You cannot have more than one table named `Table3` in a workbook, so you need to find a  generic way to do this e.g. if there is only one table per worksheet you would go with `ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)`. You don't want to use numbers especially not letters for columns in a structured table since you have the benefit of using the headers. So why don't you describe the tables more accurately e.g. do they all start in column `A`, is `S` the last column, what is `C:R` and what are all of the mentioned column's titles(headers). Could you share a screenshot of one of your tables?